# django forms DateTimeInput widgets instace value

Tags: python, django, widget

I have in Django class base UpdateView with form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['name', 'element', 'time_strat', 'time_end']

        widgets = {
            'time_strat': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
            'time_end':  forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'})     
        }
```

and without widgets the view renders (with values in the date time field):
[form without widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl8hH.png)

with widgets i have date time picker but without values:

[form with widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8jYE.png)

How to have a values in DateTimeInput widget (date time picker and instance value)?

Answer (score 5):

solved,
for it to work, appropriate format need to set: 2021-07-01T01:00 or 2021-01-01T01:00:00.

```
 'time_end':  forms.DateTimeInput(format=('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'), attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'})
```